Walk forwards optimization Rcpp code crashes Rstudio
I am trying to implement walk forward optimization using Rcpp R package. I don't have expirence wih Rcpp and C++, so kindly ask for help.
Here is the Rcpp code that implements simple backtesting function in Rcpp and one longer function thatt optimizes parameters on walk forward basis:
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). Learn


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double backtest_cpp_gpt(NumericVector returns, NumericVector indicator, double threshold) {
  int n = indicator.size();
  NumericVector sides(n, 1.0); // Initialize with 1s

  for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) { // Start from 1 since we look back one period
    if(!NumericVector::is_na(indicator[i-1]) && indicator[i-1] > threshold) {
      sides[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  double cum_returns = 1.0; // Start cumulative returns at 1
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cum_returns *= (1 + returns[i] * sides[i]);
  }
  return cum_returns - 1; // Adjust for initial value
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List combined_walk_forward_opt(NumericVector returns,
                               List indicators,
                               NumericVector thresholds,
                               int window) {
  int n = returns.size();
  // Check if window size is valid relative to data size
  if (window > n) {
    stop("Window size exceeds available data.");
  }

  int nWindows = n - window + 1;
  List results(nWindows);

  // Debug outputs to understand the state of data at each step
  Rcout << "Window size: " << window << "\n";
  Rcout << "Number of returns: " << n << "\n";
  Rcout << "Calculated windows: " << nWindows << "\n";

  // Loop over n on rolling window
  for(int i = 0; i < nWindows; ++i) {
    // Debug
    Rcout << "We are at step " << i <<"\n";

    NumericVector returns_window = returns[Range(i, i + window - 1)];
    Rcout << "We are here: ";

    // Start of embedded opt function logic
    int n_thresholds = thresholds.size();
    NumericVector sr(n_thresholds);

    // Loop over n_thresholds and calculate the backtest results
    for(int j = 0; j < n_thresholds; ++j) {
      NumericVector indicator_ = as<NumericVector>(indicators[j]);
      sr[j] = backtest_cpp_gpt(returns_window, indicator_, thresholds[j]);
    }
    // End of embedded opt function logic

    results[i] = sr;
  }

  return results;
}

after I call it in R script
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)


list.files("tmp")
returns_wf    = fread("tmp/returns_wf.csv")[[1]]
thresholds_wf = fread("tmp/thresholds_wf.csv")[[1]]
vars_wf       = fread("tmp/vars_wf.csv")[[1]]
df            = fread("tmp/df.csv")
backtest_data = fread("tmp/backtest_data.csv")

# Prepare vars
vars_wf_l = lapply(vars_wf, function(x) backtest_data[, get(x)])

# Source Rcpp
Rcpp::sourceCpp("backtest.cpp")

# Walk forward optimization test
combined_walk_forward_opt(returns = returns_wf[1:22700],
                          indicators = vars_wf_l,
                          thresholds = thresholds_wf,
                          window = 90 * 252)


it crashes my Rstudio. I don;t get any error, it just chrashes. Does it mean this is memory problem ?

A memory problem is indeed likely in this case. Can you run the R script outside of RStudio on a CLI? This typically gives you more error messages.

I have tried to run the R script in cmd with Rscript command. But got the same messages.

Please try to minimize it, and to make it self-contained with a (mock ?) sample data set we can try.  It is near impossible to help you otherwise.

"i dont get any error" + "  run the R script in cmd with Rscript command. But got the same messages." ; how do we square these statements ?
